# Connect to a complex SOAP Web Service

Tags: xml, r, curl

I'm tryng to use to this web service in order to get financial information but since I know very little about this language I find it very hard to even connect:

http://www2.sentinelperu.com/ws/asentinelws02.aspx?wsdl

I would really appreciate any help. So far I tried this:

```
    library(RCurl)

    headerFields =
     c(Accept = "text/xml",
     Accept = "multipart/*",
     'Content-Type' = "text/xml; charset=utf-8",
     SOAPAction = "http://www2.sentinelperu.com/ws/asentinelws02.aspx?wsdl")

    body = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <soap:Envelope
            xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-envelope"
            soap:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-encoding">

            <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-                         instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"  xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-envelope">
            <soap:Body>

            <Usuario>XXXX</Usuario>
            <Password>XXXX</Password>
            <Servicio>005</Servicio>
            <Tipodoc>42945948</Tipodoc>
            <Nrodoc>06594002</Nrodoc>

            </soap:Body>
            </soap:Envelope>'


            curlPerform(url = "http://www2.sentinelperu.com/ws/asentinelws02.aspx?wsdl",
            httpheader = headerFields,
            postfields = body
            )
```

The output is:

```
     OK 
     0 
     <?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
     <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
     </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing wrong with the R part, but you have to respect the namespaces in your request - change the body to:

```
body <- 
  '<soapenv:Envelope 
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
    xmlns:afp="AFPrivado">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
      <afp:SentinelWS02.Execute>
        <afp:Usuario>XXXX</afp:Usuario>
        <afp:Password>XXXX</afp:Password>
        <afp:Servicio>005</afp:Servicio>
        <afp:Tipodoc>42945948</afp:Tipodoc>
        <afp:Nrodoc>06594002</afp:Nrodoc>
      </afp:SentinelWS02.Execute>
    </soapenv:Body>
  </soapenv:Envelope>'
```

Response:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <SentinelWS02.ExecuteResponse xmlns="AFPrivado">
      <Cnsdtconrapsms xmlns="AFPrivado">
        <Documento>06594002</Documento>
        <RazonSocial />
        <FechaProceso>1900-01-01</FechaProceso>
        <Semaforos />
        <Score>0.0000</Score>
        <NroBancos>0</NroBancos>
        <DeudaTotal>0.00</DeudaTotal>
        <VencidoBanco>0.00</VencidoBanco>
        <Calificativo />
        <Veces24m />
        <ScorePromedio>0.0000</ScorePromedio>
        <SemaActual />
        <SemaPrevio />
        <SemaPeorMejor />
        <Documento2 />
        <EstDomic />
        <CondDomic />
        <DeudaTributaria>0.00</DeudaTributaria>
        <DeudaLaboral>0.00</DeudaLaboral>
        <DeudaImpaga>0.00</DeudaImpaga>
        <DeudaProtestos>0.00</DeudaProtestos>
        <DeudaSBS>0.00</DeudaSBS>
        <TarCtas>0</TarCtas>
        <RepNeg>0</RepNeg>
        <TipoActv />
        <FechIniActv />
        <CodigoWS>1</CodigoWS>
      </Cnsdtconrapsms>
    </SentinelWS02.ExecuteResponse>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

To read the result you will need this:

```
h = basicTextGatherer()
response <- 
  curlPerform(url = "http://www2.sentinelperu.com/ws/asentinelws02.aspx?wsdl",
    httpheader = headerFields,
    postfields = body,
    writefunction = h$update
  )


# parse the result    
library(XML)
xml_ret <- xmlParse( h$value(), asText = TRUE)

# get the score value for example:
score_element <- getNodeSet(xml_ret, "//x:Score", namespaces = c(x = "AFPrivado"))[[1]]
score_value  <- XML::xmlValue(score_element)
```

Comment: It almost worked but when I include password and username(Usuario), I get an error message if I execute xml_ret:> xml_ret <- xmlParse( h$value(), asText = TRUE)
xmlns: URI AFPrivado is not absolute

Comment: You can see the response with `cat(h$value())`. I guess it has some XML issues but if the errors are not fatal the `xml_ret` should contain the parsed XML.

Comment: Additional comment: the issue is that this service response is using relative URI references in namespace declaration (_AFPrivado_ instead of _http://.../..._). The parser will produce a warning but will not stop with error.

Comment: You were right. The problem was in the input parameters.